# Perforce ignore subdirectories with p4ignore

Tags: perforce

I have a .p4ignore file and it does the job for the most part but I am trying to ignore certain subfolders but it does not seem to work.

```
# Ignore .meta, csproj files at the moment 
*.meta
.DS_Store
# Ignore these folders
Data
Library
obj
# Ignore these subfolders
Resources/Subfolder1
Resources/Subfolder2
```

The resources folder is in the same directory as the .p4ignore yet it still checks out Subfolder1 and Subfolder2 into the changelist. It ignores Data, Library and obj. What am I missing?

Comment: your file worked for me. It would be helpful if you could let us know which Perforce Client program you were using when you added the files (P4, P4V, etc). Also let us know which Server Version was being used.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you need to append `/**` in order to get Perforce to ignore the contents of a directory, so in your example:

```
Resources/Subfolder1/**
Resources/Subfolder2/**
```